# Error Cannot GET / en Nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Me aparece el error Cannot GET / en el navegador y estoy probando por en vez de poner una ruta que se llame app.get, poner una que es app.post y así me sale el error, he probado a desinstalar node, eliminar los ficheros temporales, etc. Si me pueden ayudar, se lo agradecería, les dejo el código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

P.D: No se si es por lo del data, pero puede haber una solución no?
Muchas gracias por las respuestas amigos!!

Acabo de probar con postman y claramente aparece porque se puede enviar peticiones POST!!

---

```js
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const querystring = require('querystring');
const util = require('util');
const md5 = require('blueimp-md5');
const app = express();
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const urlMongo = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
let dataString = '';
let dataObject = '';
let usuario = '';
let fichero = './src/views/login.html';

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    fs.readFile(fichero, function (error, contenido) {
        if (error) { 
            throw error;
        }
        response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html charset=utf-8' });
        response.write(contenido);
        response.end();
    });
    app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/css'));
});

app.post('/login', (request, response) => {
    request.on('data', function (data) {
        // Obtenemos los datos en cadena de texto
        dataString += data;
    })
    .on('end', function () {
        // Convertimos la cadena de texto dataString a un objeto
        dataObject = querystring.parse(dataString);
        // Convertimos el objeto a JSON
        let dataJSON = util.inspect(dataObject);
        // Recogemos los datos
        usuario = dataObject.usuario;

        comprobarDatos();
        response.end();
    })
});


// Función para comprobar los datos que introduce el cliente
async function comprobarDatos() {
  let tipo = 9;

  const client = await MongoClient.connect(urlMongo, { useUnifiedTopology: true })
      .catch(err => { console.log(err); });

  if (!client) {
      return;
  }

  try {
      const db = client.db("administraciontest");
      let collection = db.collection('usuarios');
      let query = {"usuario" : usuario , "password" : md5(dataObject.password)};
      let result = await collection.findOne(query);

      tipo = result.tipo;
      console.log(result);
      console.log(tipo);

  } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
  } finally {
      client.close();
  }
  console.log(tipo);
  return tipo;
  
}

function paginaError(response){
    fs.readFile('./src/views/error.html', function (error, contenido) {
      if (error) { 
        throw error;
      }
      response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html charset=utf-8' });
      response.write(contenido);
      response.end();
    });
}

app.listen('8080', () => {
    console.log('Servidor ejecutándose en http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Administración Test - Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/login.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container mt-2">
        <h1 class="text-black-50 text-center">Inicio de Sesión</h1>
        <form action="/login" name="login" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-4 mt-4">
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Usuario</label>
                        </div>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Escribe tu usuario aquí"
                            required>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-4 mt-2">
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Contraseña</span>
                        </div>
                        <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password"
                            placeholder="Escribe su contraseña aquí" required>
                    </div>
                    <div id="respuesta">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mx-auto mt-4 buttons">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success iniciar">Iniciar Sesión</button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger borrar">Borrar</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.slim.js"
        integrity="sha256-sCexhaKpAfuqulKjtSY7V9H7QT0TCN90H+Y5NlmqOUE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
</body>

</html>
```

Acabo de probar con postman y claramente aparece porque se puede enviar peticiones POST!!

Comment: Puedes agregar el código?

Comment: tengo esa estructura, y si lo cambio por GET me funciona, pero lo quiero por POST para que no me muestre los datos de un formulario, ya que lo que estoy haciendo es un login, pero ya te digo es problema de node.

Comment: puedes explicarme concretamente lo que intentas hacer y cual es el error que causa tu código? te espero

Comment: intento que express use el método POST y cuando lo ejecuto me aparece este error: Cannot GET / , de que necesita que se use el método GET en vez del POST, pero como digo que a un compañero le ha funcionado y tenemos el mismo código y a mi no

Comment: y he probado de desinstalarlo y volverlo a hacer y no se que hacer más

Comment: Si intentas agregar el archivo en esta línea, algo asi: **app.get('/index.html'**

Comment: Pasa que node necesita un endpoint de entrada al momento de ejecutarse, y por defecto el endpoint deberia ser `router.get('/', ...)`, pero eso no significa que no puedes crear otros endpoints para lo que necesites. Tomalo como si fuera el index.html de una pagina web. Ten en cuenta que al realizar un `POST`, estas haciendo un request hacia una `API`, lo cual no deberia ser por defecto

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera, lo que comentas: *node necesita un endpoint de entrada al momento de ejecutarse*, no es totalmente cierto. El problema con la pregunta del OP es que está incompleta. No sabemos cómo hace la solicitud, lo que si es cierto es que la misma es una solicitud tipo `GET`, y si su servidor no tiene configurada una ruta para dicho método el error que recibe es el error por defecto de Express.

Comment: @Bicho en vez de abrir el fichero por GET lo quiero abrir por POST y ya no me mostrará la información de un formulario que tengo en el html si no me aparece esta y no es seguro

Comment: @CraftianosHd, creo que es un problema de conceptos. Las peticiones que se hacen en el navegador son GET. Es por esto por lo que al sustituir la implementación del verbo GET por el verbo POST en node ahora no te funciona. Puedes usar herramientas como postman o hacer llamadas mediante curl para probar esas peticiones. En dichas herramientas configuras cómo tiene que ser la petición: verbo, url, parámetros de entrada, cabeceras etc, y al lanzarlas visualiza el resultado. Te recomiendo postman porque es bastante amigable y facil de usar. Espero que te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: y a que se debe que a un amigo mio que tiene el mismo código y ejecutandolo en Firefox si le aparece, es que se deberia comportar de la misma manera no?

Comment: No estás consumiendo tu API de manera correcta. Envías una solicitud `GET`. Eso es lo que pasa. Podrías incluir un [mcve] de la forma como consumes tu API? Dices que un amigo ejecuta el codigo en *Firefox*, pero no muestras cómo lo ejecutas. ¿Cuál es la solicitud que haces desde Firefox? Envias un formulario? O simplemente escribes la dirección de tu servidor en la barra de direcciones y das `enter`? Saludos

Comment: Declara las configuraciones de tus rutas antes del router.

Comment: simplemente el lo ejecuta en el navegador y le va correctamente @MauricioContreras

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas **POST** ni **GET** para acceder al servidor, eso debido a que no es necesario hacer ninguna de estas peticiones para crear un servidor, ahora bien solo te faltaba lo siguiente:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
const http = require("http");

//Se crea el servidor http con el cual podras hacer POST y GET
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.write('Hello World!');
  res.end();
}).listen(8080);

//Aquí en medio puede ir tu código.

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));
```

De esta manera con el modulo `http` te debe funcionar, si es cierto, fuí directamente y al parecer por alguna razón no me funciono, así que investigue y dí con el modulo http.

entonces nada mas ahora debes ir a `localhost:8080` y debe funcionar, recuerda tener un index.html que renderizar en '/' y ademas reiniciar el servidor una vez hechos los cambios.

Comment: Y sacando esa línea que mencionas, como le explicarias al OP que va a seguir mostrando el mensaje cannot GET? Porque lo seguirá mostrando igual.

Comment: Hace poco cree las carpetas instale express e hice lo de mi respuesta y el servidor funciono, tambien para ello cree una carpeta css en la que tengo mi index.html, el cuál fue renderizado de manera correcta y normal. Una vez ejecutandose el servidor en nodejs fuí a la direccion localhost:8080 y funciono de manera correcta.

Comment: Recuerda reiniciar el server desde la terminal antes de probarlo, de lo contrario siempre tendras el mismo error por que no se esta actualizando el servidor.

Comment: Tu respuesta es muy temeraria. *No necesitas* es mucho decir. Intenta explicar mejor tu razonamiento. Un buen diseño de rutas usará siempre los métodos `http`. Es lo más recomendable para separar correctamente la lógica de las solicitudes. Saludos

Comment: lo tengo como tu dices @Riven, pero cuando no pongo ninguna ruta GET me aparece el error de que necesita una y no se que realizar más, porque a un amigo le va y solo ha cambiado el GET por POST

Comment: Lo siento, si tenias razón @MauricioContreras hubiese seguido dando ese error, pero con el modulo http se soluciona, checa mi respuesta editada Craftianos Hd, ahora puede funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

//`POST` y `GET` son distintos metodos par poder enviar y/o recibir informacion del navegador, comunmente, `POST` se utiliza para poder traer datos sensibles del frontend al backend de forma se gura por asi decirlo, en cambio `GET` comunmente lo que hace es devolver/renderizar datos al frontend, si tu utilizas esto:

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  res.write('Hola');
  app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/css'));
});
```

//y decear abrir esa ruta en el navegador, por defecto el navegador te devolverá `error Cannot GET /` por que obviamente no hay ruta que renderizar ni texto que pintar, solamente esa ruta servirá para poder traer datos al backen, si haces una prueba de la ruta utilizando `POST` en  postman, lo que te devolvera es un texto que diga `hola` ya que eso es lo que devuelve, un simple texto, por que como dije, el metodo `POST` lo que hace es recibir datos y devolver datos

Comment: yo ese ejemplo lo puse por poner, lo que yo quiero es que por POST me abra un html, en el cual tengo un formulario de inicio de sesión y después por otra ruta POST me muestre los datos

Comment: porque si abro el html por GET me muestra los datos del formulario en el navegador y eso no es seguro

Comment: porque a lo mejor se puede configurar el navegador para que responda peticiones POST no, porque a mi amigo en Firefox le va y tenemos el mismo código

Comment: por que dices que los datos del formulario se ven en el navegador? en que parte del navegador se ven?

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106884/discussion-on-answer-by-enzo-error-cannot-get-en-nodejs).

Answer (score 0):

`response.write()` se utiliza para mandar "chunks" (pedazos) de información al buffer. Una vez que estés listo para mostrar el resultado, llamas `response.end()`:

```
app.get("/", (request, response) => {
  response.write("uno, ");
  response.write("dos, ");
  response.write("tres..");
  response.end();
});
```

Si en cambio prefieres mandar algo de forma directa:

```
app.get("/", (request, response) => {
  response.send("uno, dos, tres..");
});
```

Mas info sobre `reponse.write()` [aquí](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.7/api/all.html#response.write)

Comment: no es eso lo que quiero hacer, está actualizado la explicación, pero gracias por detallar el significado :D